# "Attribute name x associated with an element type "item" must be followed by the ' = ' character"?

Tags: android, attributes

I have this list of car brands in my strings.xml file:

```
        <item Abarth></item>
        <item Acura ></item>
        <item Alfa Romeo ></item>
        <item AMC ></item>
        <item Aston Martin></item>
        <item Audi ></item>
        <item Bentley ></item>
        <item BMW ></item>
        <item Buick ></item>
        <item Cadillac ></item>
        <item Chevrolet ></item>
        <item Chrysler ></item>
        <item Citrogen ></item>
        <item De Tomaso ></item>
        <item Devon ></item>
        <item DeLorean ></item>
        <item Dodge ></item>
        <item Eagle Talon ></item>
        <item Ferrari ></item>
        <item Fiat ></item>
        <item Ford ></item>
        <item GMC ></item>
        <item Holden ></item>
        <item Honda ></item>
        <item Hummer ></item>
        <item Hyundai ></item>
        <item Infiniti ></item>
        <item Jaguar ></item>
        <item Jeep ></item>
        <item Joss ></item>
        <item Kia ></item>
        <item Koenigsegg ></item>
        <item Lamborghini ></item>
        <item Lancia ></item>
        <item Land Rover ></item>
        <item Lexus ></item>
        <item Lotus ></item>
        <item Maserati ></item>
        <item Mazda ></item>
        <item McLaren ></item> 
        <item Mercedes-Benz ></item>
        <item Mercury ></item>
        <item Mini ></item>
        <item Mitsubishi ></item>
        <item Morgan ></item>
        <item Aero ></item> 
        <item Mosler ></item>
        <item Nissan ></item>
        <item Oldsmobile ></item>
        <item Opel ></item>
        <item Pagani ></item>
        <item Panoz ></item>
        <item Peugeot ></item>
        <item Plymouth ></item>
        <item Pontiac ></item>
        <item Radical ></item>
        <item Renault ></item>
        <item Rossion ></item>
        <item Ruf ></item>
        <item Saab ></item>
        <item Saleen ></item>
        <item Saturn ></item>
        <item SSC ></item>
        <item Scion ></item>
        <item Seat ></item>
        <item Shelby ></item> 
        <item Spada ></item>
        <item Spyker ></item>
        <item Subaru ></item>
        <item Suzuki ></item>
        <item Toyota ></item>
        <item TVR ></item>
        <item Vauxhall ></item> 
        <item Volkswagon ></item>
        <item Volvo ></item>
        <item Wiesman ></item>
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Attribute name "Abarth" associated with an element type "item" must be
>   followed by the ' = ' character.

**What does that mean?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its problem in xml syntax, see an XML may have different type of nodes and each type of node is identified by its presentation, like

Element Node may be identified by:

```
<NodeName>NodeValue<NodeName>
```

TextNode:

```
"NodeValue"
```

Attribute Node:

```
<NodeName AttributeName="AttributeValue">
```

So your Xnk has been declared to contain item nodes as Attribute Nodes, but not specifying attribute value, use instead Element Node

```
<item>value</item>
```